# How to find attribute data-comp value usign jquery find()

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-comp="component"></div>
</div>
```

I want it to find from the selector container
something like
$('#container').find('[data-comp]');
I want the output like
'component'

Comment: Read up on jQuery attribute selectors.

Comment: Exactly like that, did you try it `$('#container').find('[data-comp]').data('comp')`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP already answered the question

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the downvotes, OP may have "already answered the question" but he didn't know what he was asking for was called so he really did not answer his own question.

Answer (score 2):

Get data attribute value using **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method.

```
$('#container [data-comp]').data('comp')
```